# How can I map a Vim shortcut to open Command-T results in vertical/horizontal split?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vim

I am switching to Command-T for file searching.  I am trying to setup shortcuts such that I can type `<leader>vv` to launch Command-T starting in app/views, find the desired file, and open it in a vertical split.

I found the following which works to narrow the Command-T search to app/views:

```
map <leader>gv :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT app/views<cr>
```

How can I change that so that it opens in a vertical/horizontal split when I hit enter on the file?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to, just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> or <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to open the new document in a split view. See [Command-T documentation](http://git.wincent.com/command-t.git/blob_plain/HEAD:/doc/command-t.txt).

Comment: I realize that is one way, but I'd rather have it set to do so on enter if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is the best way, but it gets what I'm after.  Open to better ways.  Thanks for the input.

```
map <leader>vs :split :CommandTFlush<cr>\|:CommandT app/views<cr>
```